# ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined in React

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I have react-scripts v5 installed with webpack configured using react-app-rewired.

I'm using a library that gets profile pictures of instagram users which is giving me the error message.

This is the function I'm using:

```
  const ipp = require('instagram-profile-picture');

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
  ipp(inputValue.replace('@', '')).then(user => {
    console.log(user);
  });
  }
```

Button to call the function:

```
  <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Get Profile Picture</button>
```

config-overrides.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function override(config) {
    const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
    Object.assign(fallback, {
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        "assert": require.resolve("assert"),
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
        "os": require.resolve("os-browserify"),
        "url": require.resolve("url"),
        "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3")
    })
    config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
    config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer']
        })
    ])
    return config;
}
```